# Удаление из std::deque в цикле иногда пропускает элементы

Tags: c++, алгоритм, stl, итераторы, контейнеры

Задача: удалить некоторые элементы из std::deque (по условию)

Странность: для двух кандидатов, идущих подряд, второй иногда не удаляется

```
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>

const int value = 50;

int main( )
{
    std::deque<int> c{0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90};

    for (auto &i : c) std::cout << i << " "; std::cout << '\n';

    for (std::deque<int>::iterator it = c.begin(); it != c.end(); ++it) {
        if (*it == value || *it == value + 10) {
            c.erase(it);
        }
    }

    for (auto &i : c) std::cout << i << " "; std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Результат:

```
0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90
0 10 20 30 40 60 70 80 90
```

Мы видим, что число 60, идущее сразу за 50, не удалилось, хотя должно было бы

При этом для значений value от 0 до 40 удаляются оба элемента

Если добавить в контейнер еще пару элементов (100 и 110), то число 50 начнет работать правильно, а 60 и следующие за ним будут пропускать второй элемент

То есть deque по-разному работает с элементами первой и второй половины контейнера

При добавлении элементов в контейнер число 50 оказывается в первой половине, и для него так же удаляются 2 элемента

Понятно, что перемещение по циклу с использованием уже удаленного итератора может работать непредсказуемо, но странно, что для первой половины контейнера это работает без ошибки

Ситуацию исправляет постдекремент итератора при его удалении

Так цикл работает вроде бы верно для всех случаев... кроме одного:

```
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>

const int value = 0;

int main( )
{
    std::deque<int> c{0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90};

    for (auto &i : c) std::cout << i << " "; std::cout << '\n';

    for (std::deque<int>::iterator it = c.begin(); it != c.end(); ++it) {
        if (*it == value || *it == value + 10) {
            c.erase(it--);
        }
    }

    for (auto &i : c) std::cout << i << " "; std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Для value = 0 из контейнера удаляются не 2, а 3 первых элемента:

```
0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90
30 40 50 60 70 80 90
```

Внимание, вопрос: как просто и элегантно удалить все элементы по условию?

Comment: "...но странно, что для первой половины контейнера это работает без ошибки". Если вы понимаете, как устроен контейнер `deque`, то вас это не должно удивлять. `deque` - это фактически "список массивов" (или "массив массивов"). Пока вы работаете внутри одного внутреннего массива, итератор сохраняет какую-то жизнеспособность. Но как только вы выходите за его пределы - все рушится.

Comment: Нет, не понимаю :-) Точнее - не понимал, пока вы не объяснили!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Элегантно? `remove_if` + `erase` диапазона.

`erase` элемента в общем случае инвалидирует итератор:

[All iterators and references are invalidated](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/erase)

```
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

const int value = 50;

int main( )
{
    std::deque<int> c{0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90};

    for (auto &i : c) std::cout << i << " "; std::cout << '\n';

    c.erase(std::remove_if(c.begin(),c.end(),
                           [](auto x){ return x == value || 
                                              x == value + 10; }),
            c.end());

    for (auto &i : c) std::cout << i << " "; std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: У меня в реальной задаче элементы расположены не обязательно подряд, так что длина диапазона годится только для описанного тестового случая.

А вот remove_if - кажется то, что я искал :-) Спасибо!

Comment: Длина какого диапазона? Удаляемого? Дело в том, что `remove_if` просто выполняет перенос элементов, не стирая их, и возвращает итератор первого "удаленного" элемента (вернее, первого элемента после "оставшихся" в контейнере. А `c.erase` у меня уже полностью удаляет их из контейнера. Если вы не выполните `c.erase` - то увидите, что общее количество элементов осталось тем же.

Comment: Я уже разобрался, спасибо! Алена хорошо объясняет такие вещи:
http://alenacpp.blogspot.com/2005/10/stdremove-stdremoveif.html